# Eikonal Approximation in Weinberg's Lectures on Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering, semiclassical

In Weinberg's *Lectures on Quanutum Mechanics*, it is said that

$$H(-i \hbar \nabla, \mathbf{x}) \psi(\mathbf{x})=E \psi(\mathbf{x})\tag{7.10.1}$$

and an ansatz solution motivated by the WKB approximation

$$\psi(\mathbf{x})=N(\mathbf{x}) \exp (i S(\mathbf{x}) / \hbar)\tag{7.10.2}$$

the book says one can show

$$H(\nabla S(\mathbf{x})-i \hbar \nabla, \mathbf{x}) N(\mathbf{x})=E N(\mathbf{x})\tag{7.10.13}$$

which, according to the footnote, is "defined by its power series expansion", and that "it is understood the operator $-i \hbar \nabla$ acts on everything to its right, including not only $N$ but also the derivatives of $S$."

and when

$$H(\nabla S(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{x})=E\tag{7.10.3}$$

is satisfied, we could cancel terms that are zeroth order in gradient and obtain

$$\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \nabla N(\mathbf{x})+B(\mathbf{x}) N(\mathbf{x})=0\tag{7.10.14}$$

with

$$\begin{equation}
A_{i}(\mathbf{x}) \equiv\left[\frac{\partial H(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{x})}{\partial p_{i}}\right]_{\mathbf{p}=\nabla S(\mathbf{x})}
\end{equation}$$

$$B(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i j}\left[\frac{\partial^{2} H(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{x})}{\partial p_{i} \partial p_{j}}\right]_{\mathbf{p}}$$

It is not so clear to me how this works, I might have obtained a result assuming a specific form of the Hamiltonian, say the free particle Hamiltonian. But in its most general form, I do not know how to make the change of argument in the Hamiltonian.